# jQuery - Showing hidden divs from another class / div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface

So here's the problem- I have (4) boxes of equal width and height. Each box itself has 2 states, inner and outer; inner shows only when clicked, and is hidden via css. I am trying to make it so when I click on BOX1, it shows the inner box1 content, (ib1) and hides the other (3) boxes, outer box1, and makes the width of box 1 expand the full width. I know how to code this, and that part is working fine-

However, I would like to be able to toggle between the (4) boxes once at the inner box state, kind of how a portfolio would allow you to click through to another entry. I know I cannot simply do a

```
$(.ib1).hide();
$(.ib2).show();
```

I have searched and search but alas cannot seem to find anything relating. Below is the code I have so far. I really appreciate your assistance in advance.

.js file

```
$(function() {
    $( ".click" ).click(function() {
        var $box2 = $(".box2");
        var $ib2 = $(".ib2");
                if($box2.is(":visible")){
        $(".ob1").hide();
        $(".box2, .box3, .box4").hide("fade", 1000);
        $(".ib1").show("fade", 1000);
        return false;
                } else{
        $(".ib1").hide();
        $(".ob1, .box2, .box3, .box4").show("fade", 1000);
            return false;
       }
    }); 
});
```

above code works at toggling inner/outer state, the code I am have problems with is the next box button, code below:

```
$(function() {
$( ".ib1_next" ).click(function() {
$(".ib1").hide();
$(".box2 .ib2").show();
 return false;
    });
});
```

I am very new, so be gentle :) you can see a demo of what I mean here:

[demo of 4 box](http://dausprompt.com/jquery/index.html)

Comment: u mean u want something like : by clicking on 'box outer1', you will be able to show the next button (that's what u r doing right now), and by clicking on that next button it will show the inner part of box2 with next link at the end, and so on.... ?

Comment: @Nirmal yes I believe that is what I am after :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.ibox1_inner').html($('.ibox2_inner').html());
```